# Error installing Rails on Ubuntu 11.10 (Gem::DependencyError)

Tags: dependencies, rails

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 11.10, but receiving this error:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: rails requires activesupport (= 3.2.3), actionpack (= 3.2.3), activerecord (= 3.2.3), activeresource (= 3.2.3), actionmailer (= 3.2.3), railties (= 3.2.3)
```

How can I fix this?

Note: Git (1.7.5.4 ) and Ruby (1.9.2p290) are installed properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

> sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.2

And then you should be good to go.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work...

Comment: @PauloCassiano Try this: `sudo gem update --system && sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.3`